# foreach is losing values of an object

Tags: php, foreach, drupal, getter

So this a completely stupid beginner question but I spent so much time just investigating whats going on and I have absolutely no more ideas.

I'm trying to get private values of an object called "Cell" out of an CellLineRepository. The getters are working, they're getting used at a different place.

This is how my foreach looks:

```
$all_cell_lines = CellLineRepository::findAll();
$allcells = [];
foreach ($all_cell_lines as $cell) {
    $allcells[] = [
        "CellID" => $cell->getId(),
        "iPSC-ID" => $cell->getIpscId(),
        "Lab-ID" => $cell->getLabId(),
        "altID" => $cell->getAltId(),
        "project" => $cell->getProject()
    ];
    var_dump($allcells);
}
```

A `var_dump()` of `$all_cell_lines` looks good, but I'm losing "iPSC-ID" and "Lab-ID".

```
object(CellLine)#9 (79) {
[
  "id": "CellLine":private
]=>
string(1) "1"
[
  "created_date": "CellLine":private
]=>
string(10) "2019-05-22"
[
  "created_by": "CellLine":private
]=>
string(3) "314"
[
  "last_modified_date": "CellLine":private
]=>
string(10) "2019-11-22"
[
  "last_modified_by": "CellLine":private
]=>
string(3) "301"
[
  "tab_type": "CellLine":private
]=>
string(8) "internal"
[
  "lab_id": "CellLine":private
]=>
string(5) "xxx"
[
  "alt_id": "CellLine":private
]=>
string(7) "xxx"
[
  "provider": "CellLine":private
]=>
string(36) "xxx"
```

A `var_dump()` of `$allcells` looks like this:

```
    array(1) {
  [
    0
  ]=>
  array(5) {
    [
      "CellID"
    ]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [
      "iPSC-ID"
    ]=>
    string(0) ""
    [
      "Lab-ID"
    ]=>
    string(0) ""
    [
      "altID"
    ]=>
    string(7) "xxx"
    [
      "project"
    ]=>
    string(3) "xxx"
  }
}
```

Does someone have a clue?

Comment: Can you show us what your `var_dump($all_cell_lines);` looks like please ? And are you sure about your method name for `$cell->getIpscId()` and `$cell->getLabId()` is those two cause trouble ?

Comment: could you please add your result here from var_dump

Comment: added the var_dump of $all_cell_lines for first object and anonymized the data. but its filled.
For the method names: its defined like this and works for frontend stuff :/

Comment: Can you maybe please also post the output/results of one of your `var_dump($allcells);`?

Comment: `var_dump($cell->getIpscId())` and `var_dump($cell->getLabId())` in your `foreach` and see what you get. Where would `getIpscId()` get its value from?

Answer (score 0):

try this way around please

```
foreach ($all_cell_lines as $cell) {
$allcells[] = [
    "CellID" => $cell->id,
    "iPSC-ID" => $cell->ipsc_id,
    "Lab-ID" => $cell->lab_id,
    "altID" => $cell->alt_id,
    "project" => $cell->project
];
var_dump($allcells);
```

}

try to fetch using your field name in the database

Comment: unfortunately this is not working at all (just returning NULL) because the attributes are private.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, so this was crazy. I used modules of other devs but they made their permission check in the ORM not in frontend. 
This is what I found:

```
  public function getLabId() {
    return perissionCheck('lab_id') ? $this->lab_id : '';
  }
```

Thanks anyways! :)